# How to add physical machine to Ubuntu MAAS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, bare-metal, juju

I'm trying to setup MAAS cluster with two physical servers. Both the servers already booted with ubuntu 14.04, I have installed Maas on both the servers. I had one cluster region on node1 and have no idea of adding other physical machine on to this Region. Once its done, I would like to have Juju deployed on both the instance and ideally it should be able to control both from node1. Docs are bit confusing. Can someone suggest/guide me how to achieve this setup?

Comment: Having spent (wasted) about four weeks of my own time recently in a similar pursuit, I would strongly suggest that you follow along with one of the guides out there on the Internet.  The one I've just used seems to work better than others:  https://jujucharms.com/openstack-base/  This approach uses the "juju quickstart" version rather than just "juju deploy ..." over and over again and significantly saved me time.  Note that this one requires four computers each with two drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :

You need to config:
 
1. Networks
2. Cluster
3. Add pxe-boot images

Turn the node , and it will appear on on the /youip/MAAS
Dell  done this before using two servers too. Refer this [link](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/Deploying_Workloads_With_Juju_And_MAAS-14.04LTS-Edition.pdf).